# from_queryset_single vs from_tortoise_orm in tortoise (fast api)

Tags: python, sqlite, rest, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am new to Fast API and I am trying to create an api to return the students in the database.

**This below code seems to work**

```
@app.get("/{id}")
async def get_student(id:int):
    return await stud_pydantic.from_queryset_single(Student.get(id=id))
```

**this too seems to work**

```
@app.get("/{id}")
async def get_student(id:int):
    stud_obj = Student.get(id=id)
    return await stud_pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(stud_obj)
```

**But, This does not work**

```
@app.get("/{id}")
async def get_student(id:int):
    stud_obj = Student.get(id=id)
    return await stud_pydantic.from_queryset_single(stud_obj)
```

But, Both are basically trying to return a student object. right ? so, what's the difference.
It seems like I don't understand the differance between the methods from_queryset_single and from_tortoise_orm

**Here is my Student Model**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = fields.CharField(50,unique=True)
    age = fields.IntField()
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)

stud_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Student,name="student")
studRO_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Student,name="studentRO",exclude_readonly=True)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: this because `from_queryset_single` only checks for a single item where `from_tortoise_orm` is for querying for multiple items

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to await the process of fetching data from the database.

```
@app.get("/{id}")
async def get_student(id:int):
    stud_obj = await Student.get(id=id)
    return await stud_pydantic.from_queryset_single(stud_obj)
```